# std::is_class is false on a reference class

Tags: c++, class, reference, c++17, type-traits

How come `std::is_class` is `false` when I test it on a reference ?

```
int main() {
    struct foo_struct {
        int i1;
        int i2;
    };
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_class<foo_struct>::value << std::endl; // true
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_class<foo_struct&>::value << std::endl; // falae
}
```

Comment: Because a reference isn't a class. "Different isn't the same" -- Fred Picker

Comment: For those who like their information in graphical form: http://howardhinnant.github.io/TypeHiearchy.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reference types and class types are different types; reference types are not class types themselves.

As [type classification](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type#Type_classification):

> The C++ type system consists of the following types:
>
> - ...
> - compound types (see also [std::is_compound](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_compound)):
>
>   - [reference types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference) (see also [std::is_reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_reference)):
>
>     - [lvalue reference types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Lvalue_references) (see also [std::is_lvalue_reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_lvalue_reference)):
>     - [rvalue reference types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Rvalue_references) (see also [std::is_rvalue_reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_rvalue_reference)):
>   - ...
>   - [class types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class):
>
>     - non-union types (see also [std::is_class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_class));
>     - [union types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union) (see also [std::is_union](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_union)).

I'm not sure about your intent, you might apply [`std::remove_reference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference) on the type, it gives the type itself for non-reference type. So you can use it in templates for both reference or non-reference types.

```
std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_class<std::remove_reference_t<foo_struct>>::value << std::endl;  // true
std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_class<std::remove_reference_t<foo_struct&>>::value << std::endl; // true
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0OTuzAKYe2N8mdWE)

Comment: What would i use to detect that they are both structs?

Comment: @docasok733 Answer revised.

Comment: @docasok733 -- you can't detect that they are both structs, because they aren't. One is a **reference**. You can legitimately ask "a reference to what?", and look at the "what". But don't ignore the reference part; if you do you'll end up badly confused sooner or later.